# Orace: Default column value based on a filter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Hi a developer asked to add a column on a table which will have a default value of 'N', however if the entry has an id = 3 then the default value of this column should be 'Y', is there anyway I can achieve this in oracle?

Comment: I generally handle such things from application side. simply `column = 'N'; if(id == 3) then column = 'Y'; -----store row in DB------`. and if there are existing rows in DB then simply update the column with a `case when` statement for existing rows.

Comment: maybe add a trigger for this during insert?

Comment: `VIRTUAL column` with a `DECODE` function is all you need.

Comment: @Deepak Pawar: I generally not handle this in applications as the db integrity then is at risk as you might not have control of of all apps. Also from a maintenance point of view many apps may need to be updated.

Comment: Is it really the record's *ID* being 3 or not? Then we are talking about one record. Insert the record with ID 3 and value 'Y' and make 'N' the default for the column.

Comment: I would ask the developer whether he could handle this in code. You could put a default of 'N' on the column and the user could then insert a 'Y' when `id` = 3. The column will only default if it is not named and given a value in the `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the commenters who have mentioned that this is not a good database design. That said, making compromises with database design is not unusual in real-life situations.

I am not sure that a virtual column is what is wanted. The OP asked for a way to have a default; a virtual column works differently than a default constraint (e.g., with a default constraint we can insert a value other than the default into the column. The best route to take might be to use a trigger to set the "default" value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytrigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON mytable FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.mycolumn IS NULL)
BEGIN
  SELECT DECODE(id, 3, 'Y', 'N') INTO :new.mycolumn FROM dual;
END;
/
```

A trigger will also work whether you're using Oracle 10g or 11g (both of which you've tagged).

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you use `:new.mycolumn := CASE :new.id WHEN 3 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;` rather than the `SELECT` you save the cost of jumping for the PL/SQL engine to the SQL engine and back just to perform the IF test. Also I don't believe your reference to `id` will in scope without `:new.` in front.  I would also welcome a comment on using `:old` rather than `:new` here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think you are right about everything you mentioned. One might also use `DECODE(:new.id, 3, 'Y', 'N')` rather than `CASE` etc.

Comment: Remember that `DECODE` is only valid in SQL not PL/SQL. CASE is valid in both.

Answer (score 0):

**11g approach**

From `Oracle 11g` and up, you could do this in one step using `VIRTUAL columns`.

**Test case**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tab_default (
  2    ID          NUMBER,
  3    flag varchar2(1) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (decode(id, 3, 'Y', 'N')) VIRTUAL
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO tab_default (ID) VALUES (1);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO tab_default (ID) VALUES (3);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO tab_default (ID) VALUES (10);

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM tab_default;

        ID F
---------- -
         1 N
         3 Y
        10 N

SQL>
```

So, the `DECODE` function in the `VIRTUAL` column declaration handles the requirement for you.

**10g approach**

You could fulfill the requirement using -

1. `DEFAULT` value
2. `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER` whenever id = 3

Create the table to have `DEFAULT` value as 'N'. Let the trigger fire only when a new row is inserted with value in `id` column = 3, such that the trigger updates the value to 'Y'. Else for all other cases the default value would be 'N'.

Comment: why would one want to use an AFTER trigger as opposed to a BEFORE trigger?

Comment: Because an after trigger at least ensures that the transaction moved ahead. If you depend on before trigger, and make your changes based on that, there MIGHT NOT be a surety. Won't make much of a difference, however, in such cases I prefer an after trigger. By the way, I am not a huge fan of triggers as they are an action of an effect, thus a side-effect. But, in this case, if someone is not on `11g`, then it is the only way. And that's the primary reason I edited my answer and moved `11g` approach above the `10g`trigger approach.

Answer (score 0):

After adding new column to your table you can insert value in column using below query :

```
update table_name set column_name = ( case when id = 3 then 'Y'  else 'N' end );
```

At the of inserting new records you may use below approach :
1) Decide column at the time of creating insert query, you can add logic for that when you create query.
2) Create a trigger in database that should update you column value after inserting any new row to table.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very poor database design. It doesn't respect relational database normal form.
I suggest keeping that table as it is and create a new view on the table with an extra column which is calculated using DECODE or CASE WHEN ...

Comment: Not every application could be fixed overnight. And that's why we need some workarounds for a temporary period until a permanent solution is found and implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the additional value column:

```
create table table1 as
select u.*,
case when id=3 then 'Y' ELSE 'N'
  END value  
from table2 u
```